# How can I get a hard edge after using Subdivision without unnecessary edge loops?

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm modeling this chair and there are parts with a hard edge that I'm unable to recreate after using subdivision surface. Is there any way to do it instead of creating unnecessary edge loops?

File: [Chair file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15xkbj9ViLKtNGMQDo8LJWxQoeXXOZHvd/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it the classical way, with support edge loops. I wouldn't call them unnecessary edge loops as they are necessary to sharpen the edges:

[image]

But first you need to delete this edge that is overlapping other ones:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In edit mode select the edge and use mean crease in the properties panel. A setting of nearly 1 or 1 will fix the edge straight without adding geometry